# Remember the last state of the signup process

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a basic query here. My app has a bit longer signup process. While testing I came across a bug where, whenever amidst the process if the user goes out of the app or kills the app, the remaining process is just left and it migrates to the a specific page, that i want the user to usually go to already.

Example if I have 5 ViewControllers and then a default 6th and if the users kills the app on 3rd VC, and then restart the app, it'll go to the 6th vc and ignore the rest of signup.

How do I avoid this. is using NSUserDefaults an optimal option. If yes How do i exactly implement it.

Cheers!

Comment: Does it go to the 6th only after it's been killed halfway the signup process? If so, you already save state somewhere.

Comment: yes! only after its killed. by saving state you mean, saving it in a variable or something else? Please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using `NSUserDefaults` to store the previous state of an app is common. (However, apps that have a server backend may store some data there too.)

Use the keychain to sensitive data (e.g. account details). (You must never ever store sensitive information in `NSUserDefaults` because it can be read.)

What you store in `NSUserDefaults` (and the keychain) depends on your application. If fields are filled in and/or options selected during the process, you need to store that.

Be pragmatic: It's very nice to users store app state. It can however get rather complicated. Don't waste time (with chances for bugs) trying to cover situations that don't occur often.

Comment: yeah! I am not using UserDefaults for any sensitive info. Hmm. I get what you say. This was the same ideology I was applying. I was just unsure of the process!. Cheers

Comment: Glad to help! It's one of these grey areas for which it's not immediately clear what/how to do things.